# Primefaces LayoutUnit padding and scrolling behaviour

Tags: css, layout, primefaces

I'm new to Primefaces, so I hope this isn't obvious.

In short, I've created a simple full page layout with a north bar and a centre section. When I put a toolbar in the north LayoutUnit, I get a scrollbar (on Chrome, not Firefox), and I get extra padding added after the toolbar.

Any idea how to stop both problems from happening?

EDIT: see below for update...

```
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">

<h:head title="Primefaces Test" />

<h:body>
    <p:layout fullPage="true">
        <p:layoutUnit position="north">
            <h:form>
                <p:toolbar>
                    <f:facet name="right">
                        <p:commandButton value="button" />
                    </f:facet>
                </p:toolbar>
            </h:form>
        </p:layoutUnit>
        <p:layoutUnit position="center">
            <h:outputText value="Hello, world." />
        </p:layoutUnit>
    </p:layout>
</h:body>
</html>
```

[image: http://i.imgur.com/SRKGMp4.jpg]

...

EDIT 1: Moving the toolbar out of the north bar removes the scroll bars, and removing the form tags removes the gap. The trouble is, I can't use fullscreen layout like this, so it's not a solution.

```
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">

<h:head title="Primefaces Test" />

<h:body>
    <p:toolbar>
        <f:facet name="left">
            <p:commandButton type="push" value="button" />
        </f:facet>
        <f:facet name="right">
            <p:commandButton type="push" value="button" />
        </f:facet>
    </p:toolbar>
    <p:layout fullPage="false">
        <p:layoutUnit position="center">
            <h:outputText value="Hello, world." />
        </p:layoutUnit>
    </p:layout>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Outside northbar, but with form tags still gets the gap:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/aadprsV.jpg]

No gap or northbar looks better, but can't use fullscreen:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/qlwkhPN.jpg]

Answer (score 4):

Ok, so I fixed it by overriding the overflow css for the layout ui (.ui-layout-unit .ui-layout-unit-content). Hope this helps someone.

```
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">

<h:head title="Primefaces Test">
    <style>
        .ui-layout-unit .ui-layout-unit-content {
            padding: 0.2em 0em;
            border: 0px none;
            overflow: hidden !important;
        }
    </style>
</h:head>

<h:body>
    <h:form>
        <p:layout fullPage="true">
            <p:layoutUnit position="north">
                <p:toolbar>
                    <f:facet name="left">
                        <p:commandButton type="push" value="button" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <f:facet name="right">
                        <p:commandButton type="push" value="button" />
                    </f:facet>
                </p:toolbar>
            </p:layoutUnit>
            <p:layoutUnit position="center">
                <h:outputText value="Hello, world." />
            </p:layoutUnit>
        </p:layout>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

[image: http://i.imgur.com/EvrXAn0.jpg]

Answer (score 1):

To get rid of the scrollbar in the north pane and in the north pane only, I had to set the overflow css property to hidden for the content element of the north pane.
The solution suggested above will remove all scrollbars in all panes. Normally one will not want this for the content pane.

Answer (score 0):

I had to used the following in order to achieve the result described by wieland.gmeiner (with mainLU being the id of the layout unit for which I want to preserve scroll.

```
    .ui-layout-unit:not(#mainLU) .ui-layout-unit-content {
        overflow: hidden;
    }
```

Comment: You can add this to his answer with an 'edit'. It keeps things clean